# How do I implement item sorting based on votes and time since submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

Many content-aggregators, like reddit or hackernews, sort their stories with an algorithm based on a combination of the number of upvotes and the time since it has been submitted. The simplest way to implement such sorting would be to make a function in the database that would calculate the ranking for every item and sort based on that - but that would quickly become inefficient, since it would require to calculate the ranking for all the items on each query.

Another way would be to save the ranking for every item in the database. But when would I recalculate it? If I did it only when a submission was voted on, then those which were not voted on would stay with the same ranking even though they should fall because of passing time. So, what's the best way to implement such sorting? I'm not asking what's the best algorithm for that, but how it would be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store number of votes with Rails' standard [`counter_cache`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to):

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Migration for this model should create 'votes_count' column:
  #   t.integer :votes_count

  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

What about applying complex algorithm, especially one which has time as one of its variables/parameters, well, I doubt there is better way (in general – you can come up with more simple algorithm to save efforts) than recalculating rating each midnight.

In Rails, you can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem:

```
# config/schedule.rb
every 1.day, at: '12am' do
  runner Post.update_rating
end

# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Add 'rating' column in migration
  #   t.integer :rating

  def self.update_rating
    # Ruby-way
    # self.find_in_batches do |batch|
    #   batch.each do |post|
    #     post.update(rating: (post.votes.to_f / (Date.today - post.created_at.to_date)).to_i)
    #   end
    # end

    # SQL-way (probably a quicker one, but you should think on how
    #  not to lock your database for a long period of time)

    # SOME_DATE_FUNCTION will depend on DB engine that you use
    self.update_all(:rate, "votes_count / SOME_DATE_FUNCTION(created_at, NOW())")
  end
end
```

**UPD**. Response to the points made in comments.

> If we're dealing with a site that is as dynamic as reddit, we should refresh the ratings more often.

As far as I understand you consider Reddit's main page as a reference on posts sorted by rating (which is calculated using vote count and age penalty). I seriously doubt that Reddit recalculates 'age penalty' more often than once per day. Of course, it could calculate vote counts in real-time (and that's what you can do easily with counter_cache in Rails).

So when new records suddenly gets 1000 upvotes, it goes to the main page immediately. But then each midnight it will receive penalty which equals to, say, 20% of the votes it received that day.

Well, you said that we won't discuss the specific algorithm, which could be really complex :)

> Also, do you think the ranking should in addition to that be recalculated each time a post is upvoted?

Of course, nothing should stop you to update 'vote counts' part of rating in real-time (and show records based on the resulting rating). Then you can calculate 'age penalty' for each record once per day, sinking old posts a bit.

Comment: Each midnight seems to rare, I think if we're dealing with a site that is as dynamic as reddit, we should refresh the ratings more often. Also, do you think the ranking should in addition to that be recalculated each time a post is upvoted?

Comment: @M.Zdunek I've updated my answer – too little space in comments to address your points.